# Pattern matching with logic?

Tags: functional-programming, pattern-matching, ocaml

I wonder if there is a way to do something like this `(x, y < 0, z)` 
with `y < 0`

There are three cases in my example `y = 0`, `y < 0` and else.

I know how to implement this function with different approaches, but
I just like this way and want to know if this is possible in some way.

```
let rec f = function
    | (x, 0, y) -> x
    | (x, y < 0, z) -> f (x y z)
    | (x, y, z) -> f (z y x)
```

Just that you know, I removed the complexity of the tuple in the recursive call, so the function has no purpose right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a condition after a pattern using the `when` keyword. With that, you can do what you want like this:

```
let rec f = function
    | (x, 0, y) -> x
    | (x, y, z) when y < 0 -> f (x, y, z)
    | (x, y, z) -> f (z, y, x)
```

This will cause infinite recursion because `f (x, y, z)` doesn't change anything about the arguments, but I assume that problem does not exist in your real code.